# ES6 map feature

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying out es6 map datastructure, but I when I tried to iterate the map it is giving the following error

```
The error occurs on line 6:
for (let [key, val] of m.entries())

SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:951:3
```

Here is my code :

```
"use strict"
let m = new Map()
m.set("hello", 42)
m.set(1, 34);
console.log(m);
for (let [key, val] of m.entries())
    console.log(key + " = " + val)
```

Comment: I suspect your browser does not support unboxing.

Comment: What nodejs version you run it on? Supposedly too old to support destructuring assignments.

Comment: Do you understand the error message? The unexpected token?

Comment: It seems fine with Chrome and FF but if you are using Edge then ES6 destructuring might be a problem.

Comment: @Amit it may say "unexpected" but it's _valid_ syntax. Seems it's Node that doesn't support it.

Comment: @vlaz - I don't understand your point, or what this has to do with my question.

Comment: @Amit you implied that understanding of the error message is somehow very relevant. The error message, however, seems to be completely wrong. It's like typing `2 + 2` and getting an error that says "unexpected maths".

Comment: @vlaz well, in this very case understanding the error message is *crucial*. Understanding the error message would lead to realising it's not `Map` that is to blame. The error message is completely right though: the parser could not parse the source code due to unexpected token. There are only 2 reasons for that: 1. the code is syntactically incorrect 2. The used language feature is not supported by a given interpreter

Comment: @zerkms I didn't think OP implied that was the problem. There was some valid syntax using a map and it threw an error. The title is crap, to be honest, but it doesn't really blame `Map`...more like it doesn't say much at all, but still.

Comment: @vlaz "I am trying out es6 map datastructure, but I when I tried to iterate the map it is giving the following error" --- it's not in the title but the only text in the question. And it implies exactly that. Anyway, it does not worth any further discussion.

Comment: @zerkms I can only read that as a problem with the iteration, not "Map is to blame".

Comment: @vlaz right, and if one understood the error message they would know it's a parsing problem, not the runtime one.

Comment: @zerkms and, let's be honest, if you didn't have the knowledge that ES6 is not fully supported in Node would most likely leave you puzzled just as much as `2 + 2` throwing an error to do with maths.

Comment: @vlaz well, if I have a parsing error - it's a parsing error. As I mentioned above there are only 2 cases when parsing errors arise.

Answer (score 1):

that's a little bit more handy solution to iterate:

```
let m = new Map();
m.set("hello", 42);
m.set(1, 34);

for (var [key, value] of m) {
    console.log(key + " = " + value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found one solution, here is code snippet that iterates over es6 map:

```
"use strict"
let m = new Map()
m.set("hello", 42)
m.set(1, 34);
for (let entry of m.entries())
    console.log(entry[0]+" "+entry[1]);
```